# "less"-like behaviour for sqlplus queries

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Are there any tricks or commands for sqlplus that allow for traversal of database records returned by a SELECT query as if they were being send through the Linux command "less"?

I would like to select a huge number of records sorted by date and browse through them easily.

Specifically, I'm considering replacing my log files with a database. This has a log of nice properties for searching, but I'm concerned I'll lose the ability to just look at the log for anything that looks strange.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of "less" in SQL *would* be BOTTOM, as in:

```
select BOTTOM 100 *
from log
```

However, Oracle (and most other databases) do not support this feature.  So, instead, you can use:

```
SELECT top 100 *
from log
order by 1 desc
```

(I would recommend that you have an autoincrementing logid as the first column, so the above query always works.  Otherwise, you need to sort by logid desc explicitly or some other field such as the logdatetime field.)

This will work, depending on your system, up to hundreds of thousands or millions of rows.  For instance, I have a processing log that has been going snice last September that now has about 90,000 rows, and SQL Server has no problem fetching the data I need from it.

So, if you are adding dozens or hundreds of rows into the log each day, you'll be fine with SQL.  If you are adding tens of thousanda of rows, then you might need a more sophisticated approach.  In that case, I would suggest having a log history table and a current log table and periodically dumping the current table into the history.

I forgot to mention.  There are incredible benefits to having the log in SQL.  It gives you reporting flexibility, that ability to pretty easily see "what happened yesterday", and a good platform for summarization.

Comment: I thought Oracle didn't support `TOP` either.

Comment: This may do for actually getting the data. Are you aware of anything that I could use for automatically updating the ranges I select? With less, I can press up/down arrow to navigate.